# How to analyze local variables in a frame of kdump file using crash utility?

Tags: c, debugging, linux-kernel, crash-dumps

I have a kdump wherein function A calls B, B calls C, and the crash happens at C. I am able to get the arguments passed to B and C, but I am not able to figure out how to analyze the local variables in the frames of function A and B.

I also couldn't find sufficient documentation on the crash utility. "help" command is also not straight forward. Any experienced user can help please?